# How to scale up Flink job in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink (version `1.8`) job that runs in AWS EMR and it's currently sitting at a `m5.xlarge` for both the job manager and task managers. There is 1 job manager and 4 task managers. An `m5.xlarge` has 4 vCPUs and 16 GB RAM.

When the yarn session is created, I pass in these parameters: `-n 4 -s 4 -jm 768 -tm 103144`.

The worker nodes are set to a parallelism of 16.

Currently, the flink job is running a little slow so I want to make it faster. I was trying different configurations with a `m5.2xlarge` (8 vCPUs and 32 GB RAM) but I am getting issues when deploying. I assume it's because I don't have the right numbers to correctly use the new instance types. I tried playing around with the number of slots, jm/tm memory allocation and parallelism numbers but can't quite get it right. How would I adjust my flink job parameters if I were to double the amount of resources it has?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say "it depends". You'll want to double the parallelism. By default I would implement this by doubling the number of task managers, and configure them the same as the existing TMs. But in some cases it might be better to double the slots per TM, and give the TMs more memory.

At the scale you are running at, I wouldn't expect it to make much difference; either approach should work fine. At larger scale I would lean toward switching to RocksDB (if you aren't already using it), and running fewer, larger TMs. If you need to use the heap-based state backend, you're probably better off with more, smaller TMs.

Comment: Would doubling the slots per TM (without changing instance size) help with processing power? Also, if you were to give the TM's more memory, that would be with the `-tm` parameter passed into the yarn session right?

Another thing I was thinking about was to use a countWindowAll of one so that it processes each Kafka message at once. The flink job opens up a large S3 folder and reads each every line of each file. Right now, it gets overwhelmed and slow when there is a burst of Kafka messages.

Comment: "Would doubling the slots per TM (without changing instance size) help with processing power?" That depends on where you are currently bottlenecked.